CGAL side_of_bounded_circle() inconsistent
I'm currently trying to implement a project using the Hyperbolic_Delaunay_Triangulation_2 and the Constrained_Delaunay_Triangulation_2 demos from CGAL. In short, I took the Traits-class from the former demo and used it with a Constrained_Delaunay_Triangulation_2. The Traits-class is for hyperbolic geometry, and inherits from the Exact_predicates_exact_construction_kernel_with_sqrt. I added and overwrote the orientation properties, since this isn't the case in the original Traits-class from the demo. The overwritten orientation functionality uses the already implemented Side_of_oriented_hyperbolic_segment_2. This way, I managed to be able to insert points in the constrained triangulation, and non-intersecting constraints, all without any problems. But now I tried to insert intersecting constraints in the triangulation and some (for me) strange problems occured.
When I'm inserting intersecting constraints, for example a polygon with four points and one intersection point, it takes around two minutes of time to insert that. After that, the program runs very slow and lags behind. I added some std::cout comments to be able to see where the program takes it time and found out that it takes a lot of time (two minutes) in the following line _gt.bounded_side_2_object()(circle, query); (see the Hyperbolic_Delaunay_triangulation_traits_2_functions.h line 255 cgal github).
I don't understand how it's possible, that I can insert points and non-intersecting constraints without any problems, using the mentioned Side_of_oriented_hyperbolic_segment_2 from the class:Hyperbolic_Delaunay_triangulation_traits_2_functions.h. Especially the _gt.bounded_side_2_object()(circle, query); command. But when the method includes_edge(vertex_handle va, vertex_handle vb) in Triangulation_2 calls the command
orient = orientation(va->point(), vb->point(), v->point());

which calls then the _gt.bounded_side_2_object()(circle, query); command, it takes very long and is inconsistend (it takes between 5 to 120 seconds).
(see github cgal Triangulation_2.h line 1068).
I managed to bypass this problem by first changing the hyperbolic Traits-class to inherit from Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions and then by replacing the _gt.bounded_side_2_object()(circle, query); command by:
Point_2 thirdPoint = Point_2(FT(2)*center.x() - p.x(), FT(2)*center.y() - p.y());
Bounded_side bs = CGAL::side_of_bounded_circle(p, q, thirdPoint, query);

This way there are no issues:


I would really appreciate some explanation for this behaviour, why runs the _gt.bounded_side_2_object()(circle, query); so inconsistend with the Exact_prediactes_exact_construction_kernel_with_sqrt-kernel. And why does it makes a difference whether the orientation(point1, point2, point3)-method is called by the includes_edge-method.
Please let me know if I should provide more precise informations, and please be aware that I'm new to CGAL.
